# The logo is displaying incorrectly on the main Stack Overflow site

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I'm seeing the logo cropped strangely on the main site...

[image]

For reference, it should look something like this...

[image]

There is a fixed width of 30px applied to this element in the CSS:

```
.top-bar .-logo .-img._glyph {
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
```

This should be more like 150px.

Comment: [Also Reproduced in FF 61.0.1 (64-bit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvGIZ.png)

Comment: Safari 12.0 too.

Comment: repro Waterfox 56

Comment: But looks OK on Meta

Comment: IE11 and Edge too. It's brilliant! It works consistently in all browsers!

Comment: And Chrome 68 on Windows. That's the drawback of using Opera Mini for development and testing. Isn't it?

Comment: Reproducible on Chromium 68 on Debian 9.5

Comment: I noticed this a few minutes ago and immediately ran to Meta in hopes I would find a bug report on it... MY EYES!!!!!!

Comment: We're looking into this now. Sorry about that!

Comment: same. also logged out and I see the same thing. If your resolution/zoom is in the right place it looks like `!`

Comment: Fix is going out in the next build.

Comment: Hey @TimPost, has the SE build process ever been documented anywhere? I'd be interested to read about the steps you guys go through to implement changes across the sites.

Comment: @TimPost I agree, of course this is a small graphical error which can go unnoticed but it might be REALLY interesting to know how a website with such big traffic manages changes (to avoid serious errors to go live).

Comment: And... its fixed.

Comment: The QA process depends quite a bit on what part of what product you're working on. That's .. _a lot_ to document. I can say where it _breaks_ is when cross-product things clash (e.g. International fixups merge with others which accidentally merges with some stuff just pushed on teams which just merged with enterprise, etc). This much we know we need to fix, and it's probably going to mean someone at least semi-dedicated to testing while knowing in detail what _every_ product team is currently doing, so they know where to poke to see if anything breaks.

Comment: @Turnip As for continuous integration, tests, lint, etc, stuff like that? I know that's documented in probably 5 or 6 different places, some of which probably aren't up-to-date, and I'm sure none are very specific (e.g how do we test SQL failover, or Redis, etc). You could ask here or on MSE if you have a more specific question or want more granular instead of general answers.

Comment: Also reported on Meta.SE: [Stack Overflow logo weird styling in the top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315700/289905).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fixed now.

We added a new theming setting to be able to specifiy the *height* of the logo in the top bar. Unfortunately when setting the default value for that new setting … well … here's the fix:

[image: screenshot of a Github diff that replaces the incorrect "width" with the correct "height"]

Thanks for the report!

Comment: One thing I love about SO is the humility and transparency you display with your responses to bugs. Kudos.