# Stack Overflow META logo is missing META on the user page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta, logo

The MSO logo, when logged out, is missing the orange META mark on the user page.

Image of the header when logged out:

[image: when logged out]

Image of the header when logged in:

[image: When logged in]

Comment: Is this specific to SO meta or is this the case on all sites?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Firefox 62.0 (64-bit) or on Google Chrome 69.0.3497.100 (64-bit). I tried viewing the users' page both with and without the left navigation bar enabled, both logged in and not, and I tried viewing the basic users page and also people's profiles, all of them have the orange meta box. What's your setup?

Comment: Confirmed in Chome 65.0.3325.184 for Chrome OS when using incognito mode.

Comment: Replicated (Chrome v69, Firefox 62). @DavyM - I can't replicate it when signed in, only when signed out.

Comment: @DavyM, Repro'd on Chrome and FF (latest), Ubuntu, MacOS and Android.

Comment: No repro Waterfox 56, whether or not I'm logged in, Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Can't repro with firefox 63 on debian.

Comment: Note: it appears to be correct on the user search page https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users but broken on an individual's user page https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1505120/pnuts and only when not logged in. Tested IE 11 & Chrome in Incognito mode.

Comment: There are additional styles loaded when logged in (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az0bL.jpg) that seem to be missing when logged out  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxJwa.jpg)

Comment: Possibly related to this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374315/the-logo-is-displaying-incorrectly-on-the-main-stack-overflow-site